# Saving Excel Files as TSV using Macro

Tags: excel, csv, vba

I'd like to create a special button in my excel file that saves the file as TSV automatically

can anyone help me with this.. a guide or point me to the right direction. Thank you.

I'd really appreciate your help.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro while saving a file in that format?  That should get you started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, just change the path

```
Sub test()

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\User\Desktop\Book1.tsv", _
        FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: ChDir() is not required here, unless you also want to change the default directory.

Comment: But the current workBoock is renamed to _Book1.tsv_ the next action **ActiveWorkbook.Save** resave the *.tsv not the real workbook.

Answer (score 3):

This should work, and re-Enable the current real workbook

```
Sub tsv()
 ' save the current fileName for re-save later
    BookName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name
    ' select the good Sheet.Range
    Sheets("TSV-Sheet").Range("A1:N25").Select
    ' dont display alert when already exist
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    ' save TSV file
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\User\Desktop\Book1.tsv", FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False

    ' change the sheetName modified by previous SaveAs
    ActiveSheet.Name = "TSV-Sheet"

    ' Resave the real WorkBook (because the current workbook is *.TSV)
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=BookName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```